# How to save and retrieve svg image in swift.

Tags: swift, calayer, svgkit

I am new in SVG Image usage. I used svg image in iOS. I get CALayer using SVGKLayeredImageView. And change color of different part of SVG Image. Now I stuck at the point, How to save image locally with modified layers. 
This is my code. Please review it and give me good opinion.
Thanks in advance.

```
var layer = CALayer()

let svgImage = SVGKImage(named: "Bella_1.svg")

let imageView: SVGKLayeredImageView? = SVGKLayeredImageView.init(svgkImage: svgImage)
imageView?.sizeToFit()
Character_view.addSubview(imageView!)

layer = (imageView?.layer)!

func haircolor_Selection()  {
        for subLayer: CALayer in (layer.sublayers)!
        {
            print("%@", subLayer.self)
            for subSubLayer: CALayer in subLayer.sublayers!
            {
                print("%@", subSubLayer.self)
                for subSubSubLayer: CALayer in subSubLayer.sublayers!
                {
                    print("%@", subSubSubLayer.self)
                    for subSubSub1Layer: CALayer in subSubSubLayer.sublayers! {
                        print("%@", subSubSub1Layer.self)
                        if(subSubSub1Layer.name == "hair")
                        {
                            for subHairLayer: CALayer in subSubSub1Layer.sublayers!{
                                print("$@", subHairLayer.self)

                                if(subHairLayer.name == "main-colour_1_")
                                {

                                    changeFillColorRecursively(sublayers: [subHairLayer], color: image_Color)
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
 func changeFillColorRecursively(sublayers: [CALayer], color: UIColor) {
        for layer_object in sublayers {
            if let l = layer_object as? CAShapeLayer {
                l.fillColor = color.cgColor
            }
            if let l = layer_object as? CALayer, let sub = l.sublayers {
                changeFillColorRecursively(sublayers: sub, color: color)
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to save this modified svg image, Please give answer for this. Awaiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SVGKExporterNSData` to get an `NSData` object and then write that out to a file using one of `NSData`'s `write` methods. Something like (note: not tested):

```
let data = SVGKExporterNSData.exportAsNSData(image: svgImage)
data.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
```

Also, rather than all the nested loops you use to get the "hair" layer, take a look at the `layerWithIdentifier` method on `SVGKImage`. There's an example in [this list of SVGKit recipes](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2013/06/01/svgkit-2013-recipes-part-2/) -- look for "Find the CALayer that was generated from a particular SVGElement" on that page.